# Python variable memory management

Tags: python

I just wrote this primitive script:

```
from sys import getsizeof as g
x = 0
s = ''
while s != 'q':
    x = (x << 8) + 0xff
    print(str(x) + "    [" + str(g(x)) + "]")
    s = input("Enter to proceed, 'q' to quit  ")
```

The output is as follows - and quite surprising, as I perceive it:

```
255                    [28]
65535                  [28]
16777215               [28]
4294967295             [32]
1099511627775          [32]
281474976710655        [32]
72057594037927935      [32]
18446744073709551615   [36]
```

And so on. My point is: it seems that the variable x has some sort of 'overhead' with a size of 25 bytes. 
Where does this come from? 
Thanks in advance for any attempt to help me.

Comment: *Everything* is an object in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python `int` is an object, so it's not surprising that it has a small overhead.
If this overhead starts to become meaningful for you then this implies you're manipulating substantial collections of ints, which suggests to me that the [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) library is probably something you should consider.

Comment: Or even `array.array`, or `struct`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, those are good for the raw representation, but numpy brings a lot of tools for manipulation.

Comment: Yep, I agree. But sometimes, those alternatives are all you need, and they are part of the standard library.